# How to use fflush(stdin) in a simple tic tac toe input?

Tags: arrays, loops, tic-tac-toe, fflush

I'm new to C programming and I have this task that requires me to create a simple tic-tac-toe game.

I managed to create an empty board with arrays and loops. Now I am required to **get the input of the user, and place the 'X'/'O' into the board**.

Here is the code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{    
    //Declare the variables
    //Create the board
        //Initialize the board with all blanks
        //Print to screen
    //Prompt user for letter 'X', 'O' or 'q' to quit

    //declare the variables
    char board[3][4], input;
    int rows, columns;

do
    {
        //create the board
        for ( rows = 0 ; rows <3 ; rows++ )
        {
            for ( columns = 0 ; columns < 4 ; columns++ )
            {
                //Initialize array to blanks (' ')
                board[rows][columns] = '|';

                //print to screen
                printf( "%c\t", board[rows][columns] );
            }
            printf("\n\n\n");
        }

        printf( "Hit X or O. 'q' to quit\n\n" );
        scanf("%c", &input);

    } while ( input != 'q' );
}//end main
```

The task says I can use this code `fflush(stdin)` to clear the keyboard buffer, which I obviously have no idea what it is and how to use it :(

I did some research on that code and it seems to replace existing inputs and outputs..please correct me if I am wrong.

So how can I use `fflush(stdin)` in my current case?

Sam

Comment: as you said it clears the keyboard buffer, please place it before your scanf, the buffer needs to be cleared before entering input

Answer (score 0):

when you use scanf twice without a fflush between these calls, you could get a wrong / no input on your second call, e.g. because the enter of the first input is still in the buffer. scanf would return a empty string in this case.

to be absolutely safe, you can flush stdin after each scan.